# Add an image to embed when a new user joined the server

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

The purpose of the code is that when a user joined the server, embed will be sent. I attached to the question only the embed, the rest of the code works fine. But when the embed is sent, the image is missing. The image should be the avatar of the new user. If anyone knows what the answer is, please help me.

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#00bfff')
    .setTitle(`ώ€ℓȼ๏ʍ€, ${member.user.tag} `)
    .setDescription(`Member #${member.guild.memberCount}\nInvited By ${usedInvite.inviter.tag}`)
    .setImage(member.avatarURL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`avatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL) is a method on `User`, not a property on `GuildMember`, so use `member.user.avatarURL()` to get the member's avatar URL:

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#00bfff')
    .setTitle(`ώ€ℓȼ๏ʍ€, ${member.user.tag} `)
    .setDescription(`Member #${member.guild.memberCount}\nInvited By ${usedInvite.inviter.tag}`)
    .setImage(member.user.avatarURL())
```

Comment: Also, always make sure to use [`displayAvatarURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) instead of `avatarURL()`. `avatarURL()` simply links to a user's avatar, but will fail if they are using a **default** avatar. `displayAvatarURL()` will not.